# How can I read fertility dataset from Countr package?

Tags: r

I am trying to use "fertility" dataset form "Countr" package, as mentioned in:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Countr/vignettes/exampleFertility.pdf

But I get an empty dataset. Here is my code:

```
library("Countr")
d <- data("fertility", package="Countr")
nrow(d)
```

and  I get NULL:

```
> nrow(d)
NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load package "Countr" (or any other package), all datasets provided by it become available immediately.

```
library("Countr")
dim(fertility)
## [1] 1243    9
```

If you wish to load `fertility`, without loading "Countr", then use `data`. In a new `R` session do:

```
data("fertility", package = "Countr")
dim(fertility)
```

Note that `data()` makes available the dataset(s) as a side effect. 
The return value is just the name of the dataset:

```
d <- data("fertility", package = "Countr")
d
## [1] "fertility"
```

Of course, `d` is a character vector, so it's `dim` is NULL.

If only argument "package" is specified, the result gives information about the available datasets in the package:

```
data(package = "Countr")$results[ , c("Package", "Item", "Title")]
##    Package  Item        Title           
[1,] "Countr" "fertility" "Fertility data"
[2,] "Countr" "football"  "Football data"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(Countr)
d <- fertility
nrow(d)
# [1] 1243
```